# upload media to azure blob storage using asp.net web api 2

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, webapi2

I'm developing rest web api that uploads images to my azure blob, I used one of the online tutorial and got this code

```
 public class DocumentsController : ApiController
{
    private const string CONTAINER = "documents";

    // POST api/<controller>
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
    {
        var context = new StorageContext();

        // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        // Get and create the container
        var blobContainer = context.BlobClient.GetContainerReference(CONTAINER);
        blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();

        string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

        try
        {
            // Read the form data and return an async task.
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            // This illustrates how to get the file names for uploaded files.
            foreach (var fileData in provider.FileData)
            {
                var filename = fileData.LocalFileName;
                var blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);

                using (var filestream = File.OpenRead(fileData.LocalFileName))
                {
                    blob.UploadFromStream(filestream);
                }
                File.Delete(fileData.LocalFileName);
            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
        }
    }
```

it is uploading the image in my account blob container but when i open azure storage manager and access the container i get wrong format as below picture describes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZv5A.png)

can u see the content-type ? I'm not able open this path in explorer 
any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your "filename" from code below have extension included when you debuging (like .jpg, .png)? For example "image.jpg"

```
var blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);
```

Also "fileData.LocalFileName" from code below need to have file extension

```
using (var filestream = File.OpenRead(fileData.LocalFileName))
```

It doesn't have extension and for this reason you have such issue

Comment: actually, it does't have, what should i change in order to let it work

Comment: and why is the name is formatted in wrong way, I'm not getting the right name for the file

Comment: @ahmed Name for ffile is generated by Azure and this name consist of "BodyPart" in your case + Guid. You should send to this method uri which includes file extension for example: `AvatarUri = GeneralConsts.ProfilePath + Guid.NewGuid() + GeneralConsts.Jpg;`'

Comment: @ahmed Better to create some helper in which you will upload file to Azure blob which will receive image from another method, with full file name and extension

Comment: sorry Divnch but still not getting it

Comment: now its working fine but the problem is that when i store two pics with the same name, one of them gets replaced

Comment: @ahmed When you uploading picture the best way to set some Guid inside the file name. Example you can leave your file name add Guid and in the end add file extension. In that case you wouldn't have such issue

Comment: @ahmed If it has helped you (eventually) please don't forget to mark it as the answer, thanks!